# javascript return when stopping function

Tags: javascript

If I write this:

```
$('#SomeDiv').click(DoSomething);

function DoSomething() {

  if (SomeCondition === true) {
     return false;
  }

  // more code here
}
```

regardless of whether I put `return`; or `return false;` or `return true;` the code doesn't throw exceptions and the function execution stops.

Which is the best option?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to stop the function if SomeCondition is true.

Comment: All `return`s will stop function execution. From the looks of your code, `false` looks to be appropriate, but it's all semantics.

Comment: well it doesn't stop the function. it just executes the function code **until** the return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are the only options, use `return;` in this case. (read below)

If the function normally returns something (calculates something, gets some value, etc) then you definitely don't want to return anything, because you might confuse the caller.

If your function doesn't normally return anything, then it might not hurt to return anything you like, but it might still confuse callers.

I would personally rather just put an `else` after the `if`, and not use the return;. And if the function gets too large, just retractor it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to stop the function on some condition and don't care what it returns, then it doesn't matter which of the three you choose.  If you're not using the output of the function, I'd just use a simple `return;` statement to stop it executing further.